# Simple Calculation in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, math, calculation

I would like to do a simple math calculation in Wordpress, but I didn't find any information how to do it.

I want to do the following calculation:
Take a fix value and divide by 30, and then multiply with another fix value and output the result.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/calculated-fields-form/) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a plugin to support calculations. You can find the details, documentation and installation manual on the wordpress site [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/calculated-fields-form/). Almost all examples are using field values but you can replace them by a constant value if needed.